# How to Change 2 Math.floor random numbers if they are equal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate the Monty Hall Problem, if you've heard of it, and I need to add in a system that will change one of two Math.floor random numbers when they are equal. My question is how do I change a variable that is random into another if it is equal to a second random variable. If you look into the Monty Hall Problem, the wrong variable would be an incorrect choice and door is correct, I set both to be random, but obviously, they cannot both be equal. This is what I have so far.

```
        setInterval(gr, 1000)

function gr() {
     if (wrong === door) {
        door = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    }
}

         var door1 = 0;
var door2 = 0;
var door3 = 0;
var door;
var wrong; 
var attempt = 0;

var d1 = document.getElementById('door1');
var d2 = document.getElementById('door2');
var d3 = document.getElementById('door3');

setInterval(gr, 1000)

function gr() {
    if (wrong === door) {
    door = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    }
}

function dr1() {
    document.getElementById('door1').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door2').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door3').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door1').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    door1 = 1;
    if (door2 === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door2').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        door2 = 0;
    } else if (door3 === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door3').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        door3 = 0;
}
     if (attempt === 0) {
    wrong = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    door = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    if (wrong === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door2').style.backgroundColor = "white";
        change1a();
} else if (wrong === 2) {
    document.getElementById('door3').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    change1b();
      }
    }
    attempt = 1;
 }
 function dr2() {
    document.getElementById('door1').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door3').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door2').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    door2 = 1;
    if (door1 === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door1').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        door1 = 0;
        } else if (door3 === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door3').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        door3 = 0;
        }
        if (attempt === 0) {
    wrong = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    door = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    if (wrong === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door1').style.backgroundColor = "white";
        change2a();
    } else if (wrong === 2) {
        document.getElementById('door3').style.backgroundColor = "white";
        change2b();
    }
  }
    attempt = 1;
}
function dr3() {
    document.getElementById('door1').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door2').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    document.getElementById('door3').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    door3 = 1;
    if (door1 === 1) {
    document.getElementById('door1').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    door1 = 0;
    } else if (door2 === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door2').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        door2 = 0;
    }
    if (attempt === 0) {
    wrong = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    door = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    if (wrong === 1) {
        document.getElementById('door1').style.backgroundColor = "white";
        change3a();
    } else if (wrong === 2) {
        document.getElementById('door2').style.backgroundColor = "white";
        change3b();
    }
}
    attempt = 1;
}
  function change1a() {
    document.getElementById('door3').style.pointerEvents = "all";
}

function change1b() {
    document.getElementById('door2').style.pointerEvents = "all";
}

function change2a() {
    document.getElementById('door3').style.pointerEvents = "all";
}

function change2b() {
    document.getElementById('door1').style.pointerEvents = "all";
} 

}
```

Comment: Your function `gr` appears to both use and assign global-state variables `wrong` and `door`. Your function should use parameters and return values instead of mutating global state.

Comment: There must be some more code, can you share it if so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see a question in your title but not in the body of your post. I suggest you put your question in the body too.

Comment: Please edit your question, as it is unclear what you are asking. You did not declare `wrong` and `door` (we don't know what `wrong` is), it's not clear what `gr` means, and you did not explain your problem clearly enough. What is your expected result, and what does your current code do wrong?

Comment: Well is there any way to do it without going into 6 different possibilities and just using one function?

Comment: Ok, I have added a question inside the body

Comment: added entirety of code

Comment: If you try to create two different random numbers between 1 and 3, they are going to be equal 1/3 of the time. Probably cleaner to use an array [1,2,3] and grab a number out of the array to use, then grab another number from the array after it has been reduced to only two numbers.

Comment: Thanks, ecg8, I modified your approach and got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adapting your code, but it looked too messy for me to understand everything you wanted to do. So, instead, I decided to create my own, just for fun. You can get some inspiration in there.

To answer your specific question, this is the way I choose the door:

```
var selectedDoor = 1,
    correctDoor = 2,
    losingDoor = getLosingDoor();

function getLosingDoor() {
  var losingDoor;
  do {
    losingDoor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  } while ([correctDoor, selectedDoor].indexOf(losingDoor) > -1);

  return losingDoor;
}
```

**Full demo**

```js
// Create a MontyHall instance in the #app div
var myMontyHall = MontyHall(document.getElementById('app'));

function MontyHall(container) {
  var self = {
    // Will hold DOM references
    refs: null,
    // Will hold the MontyHall instance's state
    state: null,
    /*
     * Creates the doors in the DOM and in the state
     */
    init: function() {
      self.state = {
        attempts: 0,
        doorCount: 3,
        correctDoor: self.getRandomInt(0, 3)
      };

      self.refs = {
        container: container,
        instructions: document.createElement('p'),
        doorsWrapper: document.createElement('div'),
        doors: []
      };

      // Reset container
      self.refs.container.innerHTML = '';
      // Setup a container for the doors
      self.refs.doorsWrapper.className = 'doors-wrapper';
      self.refs.container.appendChild(self.refs.doorsWrapper);
      // Setup a container for instructions
      self.say('Please select a door.');
      self.refs.container.appendChild(self.refs.instructions);
      // For each door
      for (var i=0; i<self.state.doorCount; i++) {
        // Create a div
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        // Give it a class
        el.className = 'door';
        // Add click event listener
        (function(index) {
          el.addEventListener('click', function(){
            self.clickOnDoor(index);
          });
        })(i);
        // Append it to the doors container
        self.refs.doorsWrapper.append(el);
        // Store a reference to it
        self.refs.doors.push(el);
      }
      return self;
    },
    /*
     * Called when a door is clicked
     */
    clickOnDoor: function(index) {
      self.state.selectedDoor = index;
      // If this is the first attempt
      if (self.state.attempts === 0) {
        // Show it is selected
        self.refs.doors[self.state.selectedDoor].classList.add('selected');
        // Find a non selected losing door
        self.state.losingDoor = self.getLosingDoor();
        // Open it
        self.refs.doors[self.state.losingDoor].classList.add('disabled', 'loser');
        // Update instructions
        self.say(
            'You selected door #' + (index + 1) + '.<br>'
          + 'I opened door #' + (self.state.losingDoor + 1) + ', '
          + 'it contains a sheep.<br>'
          + 'You can now keep your choice, or change your mind.'
        );
        self.state.attempts++;
      } else {
        // For each door
        self.refs.doors.forEach(function(el, i) {
          // Disable it
          el.classList.add('disabled');
          // Show it as a winner or a loser
          el.classList.add(i === self.state.correctDoor ? 'winner' : 'loser');
          // Show it as selected or not
          el.classList.toggle('selected', i === index);
        });
        // Update instructions
        self.say(
          (
            self.state.correctDoor === index ?
            '<span class="green">Congratulations, you won!</span>' :
            '<span class="red">Sorry, you lost...</span>'
          )
          + '<br>'
          + 'The gold was behind door #' + (self.state.correctDoor + 1) + '.<br>'
          + '<button class="restart">Play again</button>'
        );
        // Enable restart button
        self.refs.instructions.querySelector('.restart')
                              .addEventListener('click', self.init);
      }
    },
    /*
     * Returns the index of a losing door, which is not selected
     */
    getLosingDoor: function() {
      var losingDoor;
      do {
        losingDoor = self.getRandomInt(0, self.state.doorCount);
      } while ([
                 self.state.correctDoor,
                 self.state.selectedDoor
               ].indexOf(losingDoor) > -1);

      return losingDoor;
    },
    /*
     * Sets the instructions innerHTML
     */
    say: function(html) {
      self.refs.instructions.innerHTML = html;
    },
    /*
     * Returns an integer between min and max
     */
    getRandomInt: function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min)) + min);
    }
  };

  return self.init();
}
```

```css
/* I minified the CSS to avoid cluttering my answer. Full version in link below  */body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:center}p{margin-top:.2em}button{margin-top:.5em}.door{display:inline-block;width:3em;height:5em;border:1px solid #000;margin:.5em;background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/c7mssS/doors.jpg);background-size:300% 100%;background-position:center;cursor:pointer;box-shadow:0 0 5px 1px #1070ff;transition:all .3s ease}.door:not(.disabled):hover{opacity:.9}.door.selected{box-shadow:0 0 5px 3px #b910ff}.door.loser{background-position:right}.door.winner{background-position:left}.door.disabled{pointer-events:none}.door.disabled:not(.selected){box-shadow:none}span{font-weight:700}.green{color:#42e25d}.red{color:#ff2f00}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ojsmndt3/)

Comment: Thanks, but I attempted it different and later got it to work today. By logic, if the door you chose was the correct door I made it chose the wrong one 50/50 on the other side if that makes sense. And if it is one of the other doors, and can truly only give you one option. Thanks anyway!